# What is $C_\mathrm{eq}$ for this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

What is $C_\mathrm{eq}$ for this circuit?

> [image]

I don't even know how to approach such a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Hint: [Y-Δ transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) work for capacitors just as well as they do for resistors.